# how to fetch data from many to many field objects?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, many-to-many

I am getting stuck in many to many field objects in my model i want to retrieve the price of product from the order model objects but while fetching it gives sometime many related manager error or query set error

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)



class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete= models.SET_NULL,null = True)
    product = models.ManyToManyField('Order.Product')
    is_ordered = models.BooleanField(default =False)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True,null = True)
```

views.py

```
def get_product_price(request):
    if request.method=="GET":
        user=User.objects.get(username = "hemant")
        orders = user.order_set.all()
        order = orders[0]   
        price = order.product.price
        return HttpResponse(price)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are getting value from [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/), you need to do it like this:

```
products = order.product.all()
```

If you want to get the prices, you can do it like this:

```
products = order.product.all()
for product in products:
    print(product.price)
```

If you want to return prices as a http response, then you can use [values_list()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) to get list of prices from queryset. Like this

```
import json


views.py
def get_product_price(request):
    if request.method=="GET":
        user=User.objects.get(username = "hemant")
        orders = user.order_set.all()
        order = orders[0]   
        price = list(order.product.all().values_list('price', flat=True))
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(price))
```